# First name or last name with "Sir"

Tags: names, email, greetings, honorifics

If my teacher's first name is Robert and his last name is Dowry, and I have to send him an email, then which of the following will be correct?

> 1. Dear Sir Dowry,
> 2. Dear Sir Robert,
> 3. Dear Sir Robert Dowry,

Comment: Usually, the name isn't mentioned, is it? It's just: "*Dear Sir, ...*"

Comment: First AND last name with sir: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirhan_Sirhan  -Sadly, not the question being asked.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about etiquette.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If he is knighted, it would be *Dear Sir Robert,*

Otherwise you would use any of

- *Dear Sir,*
- *Dear Mr. Dowry,*

or if you know him well or are American,

- *Dear Robert,*

Comment: Even if he is knighted, they may not use the title in the context. One of my school teachers had the title *Lady* but since she didn't use it in that context we still addressed her as *Miss* and referred to her as *Mrs. X*.

Comment: They mightn't but you should when sending them mail if you know they are in my opinion.