# when using the titles of Dr. should it be followed by their first name or last name

Tags: grammar

when in the presence of a doctor, is it proper to call him

Dr. "first name" or Dr. "last name" is there any rules that normally apply. I know in the military that you don't use Sargent "first name" it is always Sargent "last name" and the same with President " Barack or Obama"

Comment: It depends on where you are. Some places it's the last name, others it's the first. Generally it's a compliment to be on intimate enough terms to be addressed as "Dr. Firstname", at least in Asian Englishes.

Comment: In the AmE/BrE, almost always it is Dr. Lastname. Using the other sounds very strange.

Comment: HI Bruce.  It's simply **lastname**.  For Doctor.  It's that simple.  Only in uusual (jokey, family, advertising, or media) situations would you use the firstname.

Answer (score 3):

In British usage, there are very few titles which are used with the first name alone: only some honorifics such as "Sir", "Lord" and "Prince". 
Academic, professional and occupational titles (such as "Dr", "Professor", "Constable") are always used with surname, or with both name.

I have a friend who we know as "Dr Tim", but this is a sort of friendly joke, to the people who knew him before he qualified. I would be surprised to hear anybody else refer him in this way.

Answer (score -2):

Both as a reference and as a form of address, *Dr. Lastname* is the most common format, as is the case with most titles in English-speaking countries (*Mrs. Robinson*, *Cardinal Naguib*, *Private Benjamin*, *Lord Snow*). But *Dr. Firstname* is not unheard of, and depending on the relationship you have with the doctor and the setting for your interaction (including the geographic part of the world), may be unremarkable.

Anecdotally, I would expect *Title Firstname* to be more common in environments where social hierarchy is stricter, and to be more common for more exclusive titles. For example, in much of the Southern US, which is more socially conservative than the country as a whole, children might address a familiar adult as *Mr. Firstname* or *Miss/Mrs. Firstname* to be friendly but respectful. I also understand this to be practiced in India and other parts of Asia. It is not at all common where I live now, in the Washington, D.C. area, nor where I grew up, in Southern California.

But in both SoCal and DC, people certainly *do* follow this pattern for loftier titles. At my elementary school, we addressed the chaplain as *Father Patty*, not *Father O'Reilly* (or for that matter, *Father Patrick*). In my brief stint as a lowly editorial assistant at the National Research Council, despite a surprisingly collegial atmosphere, I still referred to the researchers in my office as *Dr. Judy* or *Professor Jake* instead of simply *Judy* or *Jake* (too familiar), or as *Dr. Chen* or *Professor Richardson* (too distancing).

Similarly, staff in a medical office might address the doctors as *Doctor Jim* and *Doctor Maggy* even though the patients invariably address them as *Doctor D'Angelo* and *Doctor Singh*.

Address your doctor whichever way she or he prefers: that is the long and short of it. Closely related questions include [Can "Mr", "Mrs", etc. be used with a first name?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53945) and [First name or last name with "Sir"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133473) ; also see [Disrespectful use of "mister"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145304) and  [How should I address a professor in the US?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42931)

Comment: From this answer the OP will expect to use Dr. Firstname as a default. That is quite the outlier in my experience.

Comment: Well, OP didn't specify what kind of doctor and what kind of setting, but I'll edit to clarify that *Dr. Lastname* is the rule.

Comment: In the US, TV and radio have Dr. Ruth, Dr. Phil, and Dr. Laura, as well as Judge Judy.  But that's not typical usage.